# Bootstrap dropdown-menu not working in Mac but works in windows

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple dropdown-menu. It works in my windows machine but not in my Mac. I checked through few suggestions but nothing seems to work. I tried with various versions of bootstrap.js and jQuery.js

```html
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius: 5px !important;"
    id="logincheck">Login</a>
    <ul id="login" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Some content</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the order of JS and CSS files in my HTML

```html
<script src="<c:url value="/angular.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/angular-resource.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding the dependency 'ui.bootstrap' to the angular module and had to include the script below

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```